# RSA Private Key PEM in ASN.1 Format Contains Extra Bytes

Tags: rsa, pem, asn.1

I'm looking at an RSA private key in PEM format. When I decode the base64 string and review the components of the key, some of them have an extra byte, specifically the modulus, P, DP, and IQ. They all have a leading 0x00 byte. I'm handling this by just trimming the byte[] down to the expected lengths of 256 or 128 so I can use them with .NET RSAParameters and RSACryptoServiceProvider, but wondering why some of these INTEGER structures have the extra byte while others don't. It would appear that online and other libraries that decode the PEM to XML, etc handle this gracefully, so is this part of the RFC, just something that you have to protect against, or only a concern because I'm using the .NET libraries after decoding? Here's an example of the modulus with 257 bytes:

```
00 B7 55 AA 3F 14 89 BC CE ED AF 80 1C 54 2A DF 
AB 3C 6A 44 B4 55 58 90 0E 0D 32 96 E6 EF 35 2D 
AD B7 44 A7 AB CE 6F D3 BB 9D B4 4B FD 0A DE 87 
96 03 55 23 81 49 FE 1B 3E CE 62 B6 2F B1 4C 33 
E4 F8 C2 09 5F 0E 10 78 22 D0 F3 C9 BF B9 AC AC 
11 00 17 28 09 23 10 D5 8A C9 2B E2 86 96 A7 E2 
57 68 D7 3B 63 BE 74 ED B8 02 E2 63 EF F5 40 85 
0C A6 9F D0 B6 88 36 8B 4E 6B 35 27 BE 11 CC C8 
C3 0A 66 25 E0 AB B6 DD 6D E6 2B AF 9E 1C D7 11 
CE 5F E7 C8 1F EB 3D 79 B3 B2 E1 FF D8 20 6D 76 
A2 43 9E 20 67 58 97 39 46 D8 73 F6 F0 76 01 E0 
61 8E 4A EE C4 03 A6 44 C7 D3 50 E3 C8 62 CF 33 
D1 37 6B 85 F5 D4 3C 6D 1F 1A 14 B3 30 B5 E0 82 
A5 94 83 4F 7A 17 DA 86 2B F7 2A 47 A3 5F D2 D5 
7B 96 32 86 27 5E 2A 6A 85 6E C6 24 15 A9 09 65 
BB 04 8C 0D 39 F7 15 D4 F0 F8 5F 0F B0 1D A7 2F 
D7
```

Here's an example of the "D" parameter that is not padded with a leading 0x00:

```
04 07 EF 8A 5D 88 3D C7 8B 00 5D DF C1 96 03 BE 
FF 20 1D 0C A8 07 BF 7B 1F 9D 2A 26 3F C2 3A 93 
E4 40 B5 33 18 E1 EA 94 E8 7D C0 61 EF F8 3E A0 
F4 C7 CD 75 0D 4C 72 0A EA 7C CF 26 B3 4E 4A A1 
D1 3A 6A FA 55 11 D5 A2 66 57 C5 EA DA 49 4A AB 
41 06 41 52 1A 1C 47 A5 BA 90 A5 75 72 20 94 E0 
79 24 AA 60 A2 12 6E 1B AA AC 91 A7 F8 0B 88 21 
64 14 85 81 4D F3 6D 12 B7 56 BE DD F6 04 3B B1 
CC 95 A6 8C 9D A6 8D BF 05 C1 72 A4 0B 03 75 F6 
40 B6 8E 25 91 3D 87 84 CD 23 EF 2C 29 13 DD A7 
75 6E 48 F4 DE 49 98 4F B7 09 CF 5A A3 F5 39 05 
37 C8 2B 79 64 F0 B8 AD 11 EF 79 FD 78 C0 6B 2B 
50 7F DE BC 59 3D D1 A1 90 59 B7 7E 57 B4 2C A0 
D2 20 D2 D6 7C 4A B3 3C 63 5D FA E6 67 18 58 AC 
F3 EF 0E E1 C0 C9 B6 D9 8C D1 8E 3D CE 8A FF F0 
12 BF C2 FE 72 DC 07 E4 3C 00 5B BE 05 D9 5A 61
```

And the DP parameter without leading 0:

```
3E 50 B2 28 A3 B1 71 F3 D5 31 B1 2D FD B3 60 4B 
57 F8 C1 46 C7 89 B7 95 F4 7D AE 54 F2 EA 11 98 
F7 61 93 30 50 D9 24 19 BF 7F 06 19 DB 97 01 06 
8B 20 D7 7A 5E 1A FA 76 9A 0E 27 46 AB FF 25 3C 
74 61 E2 9B 3E CE A5 F9 58 40 70 15 94 F2 58 3E 
DB E4 90 91 3C 50 B0 24 8F C7 A7 55 EB E3 59 A7 
5D 01 19 29 4F F9 F9 E6 EB 78 D1 93 14 61 E4 5C 
36 D7 E7 82 58 E7 C5 60 21 F3 1E 5A D4 49 C6 D1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RSA modulus is a positive number, and ASN.1 integers are all signed.

So if the leading 0x00 wasn't there, this byte encoding would represent a negative number because the first byte would have the high bit set (0xB7 >= 0x80).  As a consequence, the 0x00 gets inserted into the DER data stream.

.NET's representation is based on the Windows CAPI representation. CAPI uses domain knowledge to know that the values are all unsigned integers, and then omits the leading 0x00 bytes.  So it's up to whoever translates between the DER data and the .NET/CAPI data to add or remove the bytes as needed.

Comment: So, not every integer parameter is prefaced with a leading 0, for example "D" is an integer, but starts with 0x04 0x07... Should I be interpreting that as a negative number? I guess not that it matters because I'm supplying byte arrays to the .NET object, but want to make sure I understand the contents of the items to make sure the parser I wrote is interpreting them accurately.

Comment: @Crypt32, additional examples from the same key added.

Comment: See my answer. Extra leading zero is added when the most significant bit is set to 1. Otherwise, no bytes are added.

Comment: @hakenmt The padding byte is required when the first integer byte would be >= 0x80.  Since that bit is what makes it be interpreted as negative (clarified my answer)

Answer (score 3):

These values are encoded as `INTEGER` ASN type which uses two-complement notation. That is if most significant bit is set to 1, then the number is negative. However, all numbers (modulus, exponents, primes) in key are positive numbers and prepended with extra leading zero octet to denote positive integer. If the most significant bit is already set to 0, then no extra bytes are added.